# Swift вернуть массив из рекурсивной функции

Tags: массивы, swift

```
func permute(_ a: [String], _ i: Int, _ n: Int) -> [String] {
        var arr = [String]()
        var a = a
        if (i == n) {
            print (a)
            return arr
        }

        for j in i..<n {
            a.swapAt(i, j)
            permute(a, i+1, n)
            a.swapAt(i, j)
        }

        return arr
    }
    var a = ["a", "b", "c"]
    print(permute(a, 0, 3))
```

Моя функция выводит построчно массивы букв (через print):

```
["a", "b", "c"]
["a", "c", "b"]
["b", "a", "c"]
["b", "c", "a"]
["c", "b", "a"]
["c", "a", "b"]
```

А сама функция возвращает

```
[]
```

А нужно чтобы функция возвращала строки:

```
["abc", "acb", "bac", "bca", "cab", "cba"]
```

Основная проблема в том, что я не понимаю как в рекурсивной функции добавлять элементы в массив и возвращать эти элементы.

Answer (score 1):

Первая причина по которой не работает функция это что что при каждом вызове рекурсии создаете новый массив.

```
var arr = [String]()
```

Соответственно результат сбрасывается.

В Swift все базовые типы являются value type, для вашей проблемы больше подошла бы ссылка на массив который вы меняете в рекурсивной функции. Этого можно добиться назначив тип параметр `inout`. А так же необходимо указать `&` символ, который указывает что передается ссылка на объект.

Пример вашей функции может выглядеть вот-так.

```
func permute(_ a: [String], _ i: Int, _ n: Int, _ baseArray: inout [[String]]) -> [[String]] {
  var a = a
  if (i == n) {
    baseArray.append(a)
    return baseArray
  }

  for j in i..<n {
    a.swapAt(i, j)
    permute(a, i+1, n, &baseArray)
    a.swapAt(i, j)
  }

  return baseArray
}
```

Передавать необходимо следующие параметры.

```
var a = ["a", "b", "c"]
var resultArray = [[String]]()

let foo = permute(a, 0, 3, &resultArray)
```